# linux - gbdk returns a fatal error whenever I try to use it

Tags: c, linux, compilation

Gbdk works fine on windows but it doesn't work if I try it on linux:

When I run
`/usr/lib/gbdk/bin/lcc -Wa-1 -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -c main.c -o main.o`
it returns this error:

> /usr/lib/gbdk/bin/lcc: fatal error in /usr/lib/gbdk/bin/sdcc

That's it. Can anyone please help?

Running `cat /etc/os-release` returns:

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="19.3 (Tricia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 19.3"
VERSION_ID="19.3"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=tricia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Running `uname -r` returns

```
5.3.0-46-generic
```

Running `file /usr/lib/gbdk/bin/sdcc` returns

```
/usr/lib/gbdk/bin/sdcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
```

Running `file /usr/lib/gbdk/bin/lcc` returns

```
/usr/lib/gbdk/bin/lcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use https://github.com/gbdk-2020/gbdk-2020 if you were using 20 years old GBDK.

To see the actual error message run `sdcc` manually, you can feed `lcc` `-v` to see which programs it calls with which arguments.

Last time I've seen something like `/usr/lib/gbdk/bin/lcc: fatal error in /usr/lib/gbdk/bin/sdcc`, it was a segmentation fault. `lcc` sadly catches errors and replaces them with an unhelpful error message.